# Show spinner on specific table row when loading angular material

Tags: angular-material

I have a material table row like this:

```
<ng-container  matColumnDef="delete">

  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Delete</mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let data">
    <mat-spinner *ngIf="isDeleting" [diameter]="25" ></mat-spinner>
    <button *ngIf="!isDeleting" mat-raised-button (click)="deleteRecord(data.id)">Delete</button>
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

I want to make it so that when the button in the row is selected, the button goes away and the spinner shows up until the loading is completed. The above code makes all the button rows disappear and show the loading, I just want the row button that was clicked.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Trying to do something similar myself and came across this

Comment: @Josh nothing super clean but you can show the spinner based on the index of the row. So if index 5 row is selected then save `selectedButton = 5` somewhere and on each button add a condition that checks if the button index matches the saved index then show spinner.

Comment: That's a good idea. I'm going to see if I can add a prop to the object that the table is iterating over, like `loading` or something and manage it that way by setting the value on click and throughout my code. If I can't work that out yours would work nicely. Thanks for the rapid response on a relatively old question!

Answer (score 0):

Just had to implement this feature for work. So for those who stumble upon this...

To target only the row of the selected button: Update your datasource to include another element for each item called `isDeleting`, which equals `false` by default.

Upon clicking your delete button, pass the data object from matCellDef and set `data.isDeleting = true`.

Once the delete process has completed, `data.isDeleting = false`.

I would also recommend creating a variable such as `this.selectedRecord` and set that equal to `data` upon button click, therefore it'll be easily accessible further in your code during the deletion process.

Ultimately, utilize `this.selectedRecord.isDeleting = true/false`.

To show delete button: `*ngIf="!this.selectedRecord.isDeleting"`.

To show progress spinner: `*ngIf="this.selectedRecord.isDeleting"`.

And remember to update the boolean to false once deletion is completed.